# React navigation how to deep link

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation, deep-linking

I have a React Native using Expo app. I'm managing the user registration into the app. To do so, once the user clicks on the register button, I send an email to him with a URL to validate the account. Once the user clicks on the URL, if he's on the phone, I want it to open the app if it's installed, otherwise open the browser. If he opens the url from desktop, then I want it to open the browser.

1. How should the URL be passed? (What kind of URL, let's say I want to navigate to `https://example.com/validateAccount`)
2. How can I test it locally?
3. How do I tell the app to open if installed? Because, the URL to be passed should be a `https://example.com` to be able to open it from a web browser

Linking config:

```
  prefixes: [
    "http://192.168.1.13:19006",
    "http://localhost:19006"
  ],
  config: {
    screens: {
      root: { ...}
    }
 }
```

Comment: Yes. But it's not clear for me. Let's say my email URL is: `http://192.168.1.13/validateAccount`. I'm on my phone. I tap on the link, it opens chrome, not the Expo Go app. How do I test it locally? Because I want also to be able to access through desktop web browser. How do I have to configure my linking prefixes?

Comment: Still not clear on how to test it locally.. but I appreciate it! I'll keep looking

Comment: Well, I'm using Expo. I cannot make it work to send this url `http://192.168.1.13/validateAccount` being opened by my Expo Go app. It always opens  chrome. Check my linking config I edited.

Answer (score 0):

refer to Deep-linking official doc of react navigation.
[Deep Linking](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/deep-linking/)